# dwm does not show any windows after login

Tags: troubleshooting

Ubuntu 12.04, DWM 6.0

When I login to my Ubuntu box, only DWM toolbar is shown on the top of the screen. Everything else is filled with the Ubuntu login screen remains, inactive.

I guess this happened after one of the updates — earlier DWM worked fine, but became broken after a reboot.

Any clues on how to fix that? I was not able to google up a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling `dwm` helped.

```
$ apt-get --reinstall install dwm
```